# Can a smartphone supply a entire circuit with NFC

Tags: nfc

I'm new to NFC and fairly new to programming as well.

I'm doing some research on NFC for a project that Im working on. I have an embedded device and a tag that I need to get to communicate.

I would like to know the following:
1 - it is possible to generate enough power to connect the whole circuit and a M0 cortex only using my smartphone (I'm talking about 50mA).
2 - it is possible to write and read in the tag with both the M0 chip and the smartphone in the tag that will be connected in the circuit.

Thank you and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are NFC chips that can supply power to other circuitry (check chips from e.g. NXP, AMS, Silicon Craft, maybe others). However you will only get a few mA (<10mA) from NFC.

Such NFC chips have a serial interface like I2C bus for the connection to a µC. Both the smartphone via NFC, as well as the µC can read/write to the memory of the NFC chip.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed to know.